# changing color of squares in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make simple program in which you can press squares on screen and they will change color, but i can't find in documentation how to do it with `pygame.draw.rect`.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode([501, 501])

siatka = [[[0] for i in range(10) ]for i in range(10)]

def rysowanie():
    for i,el in enumerate(siatka):
        for j,ele in enumerate(el):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),pygame.Rect(50*j +1,50*i+1,49,49))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))

    rysowanie()

    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
```

I don't even have an idea what is the name of the thing i want to do, so if this is very easy I'am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `siatka` a matrix of colors, and for each square, draw its corresponding color.
When the screen is clicked, change the color in `siatka` for that mouse position.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([501, 501])
siatka = [[(0, 0, 0) for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

def rysowanie():
    for i, el in enumerate(siatka):
        for j, ele in enumerate(el):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ele, pygame.Rect(50 * j + 1, 50 * i + 1, 49, 49))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            siatka[event.pos[1] // 50][event.pos[0] // 50] = (255, 0, 0)
    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    rysowanie()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```